# How to take value from i+1th column of 1 df and calculate distance to values in every row in i+1th column of 2nd df

Tags: r, for-loop, coordinates

Suppose I have the following two dataframes (with uneven rows)

```
set.seed(1999)
dfA <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))

set.seed(24)
dfB <- data.frame(a = rpois(10,2), b = rpois(10,2), c = rpois(10,2), d = rpois(10,2), e = rpois(10,2))

set.seed(10)
Dx <- sample.int(5)
set.seed(6)
Dy <- sample.int(5)

Dx <- as.data.frame(Dx)
Dx <- as.data.frame(transpose(Dx))
Dy <- as.data.frame(Dy)
Dy <- as.data.frame(transpose(Dy))

dfAB <- map2_df(dfA, dfB, str_c, sep=",") %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))
dfXY <- map2_df(Dx, Dy, str_c, sep=",") %>%
  rename_all(~ str_c('C', seq_along(.)))
```

Now I have 2 datasets of coordinates (dfAB 5 variables each with 10 observations, dataset dfXY 5 variables with 1 observation).

What I would like to do is to find the distance between the observation of variable 1 of dfXY and every individual observation in variable 1 of dfAB, the distance between observation 1 of variable 2 of dfXY and every individual observation in variable 2 of dfAB, etc.

```
dfAB                          dfXY
3,1   3,2  ...       3,5  1,2  2,1  5,4  4,3   
2,1   3,1                  
2,3   1,2               
...   ...
```

i.e. the distance between: a) 3,5 & 3,1 b) 3,5 & 2,1 c) 3,5 & 2,3 etc...
and the distance between: a) 1,2 & 3,2 b) 1,2 & 3,1 c) 1,2 & 1,2 etc..
and so on.

If the datasets had equal amount of observations I could use:

```
distances <- map2_df(
  dfAB,
  dfXY,
  ~ sqrt((.x$x - .y$x)^2 + (.x$y - .y$y)^2)
)
```

But since dfXY only have 1 observation (to be compared with repeatedly), this does not work. I think I need to use something like a `for(i in seq_along())` function but I do not know how to incorporate the `~ sqrt((.x$x - .y$x)^2 + (.x$y - .y$y)^2)`

```
distance <- for(i in seq_along(dfXY)){
  dfAB[,i] <- dfAB[,i] [WHAT TO PUT HERE]
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The second example is throwing errors `df_cdt <- as_tibble(lapply(map2(dfC, dfD, ~ list(x = .x, y = .y)), as.data.frame))`  Please specify a `set.seed`

Comment: It could be related to `dfC <- c(1:5);
dfD <- c(11:15)` i.e. these are vectors

Comment: The first thing you should do is execute this with `set.seed(.)` specified and then you can present results that allow accuracy checking.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to fix the dfC and dfD, the ```df_cdt <- as_tibble(lapply(map2(dfC, dfD, ~ list(x = .x, y = .y)), as.data.frame)) ``` should work now (see changes above)

Comment: As others have already mentioned can you use `set.seed` to generate the data so we have same data as yours and then show expected output based on that?

Comment: Apologies for the rookie mistakes. I have edited the post to include some seeds and tried to put it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a bit of a hard time following what you're trying to do here, but I think you may be making things too needlessly complicated for yourself.

For example, instead of nesting `map2()` call inside a `lapply()` call, I think you can achieve pretty much the same result without iteration using `bind_cols()`:

```
dfA <- tibble(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfB <- tibble(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))

df_abt <- dfA %>%
  bind_cols(dfB) %>%
  select(x, x1, y, y1, z, z1, q, q1, t, t1)
```

For dataframes C and D, you can use iteration with map to avoid having to transpose them:

```
dfC <- map(1:5, ~ .x) %>% bind_cols()
dfD <- map(11:15, ~.x) %>% bind_cols()

df_cdt <- dfC %>%
  bind_cols(dfD) %>%
  select(V1, V11, V2, V21, V3, V31, V4, V41, V5, V51)
```

(actually why not just store df_cdt as a vector? is there a reason it needs to be a data frame?)

As for distances, I reckon this should work:

```
df_dist <- map2_df(df_abt, df_cdt, ~ sqrt((.x - .y)^2))
```

If you have an unequal number of rows in df_abt, why not just pad out the missing rows with NA's? I mean, it won't let you build a dataframe with columns of different length anyway.

Comment: The odd setup is to make the example mirror the structure of my actual. I have tried to rewrite the question to make it more clear. Also please note that my actual dataset is thousands of rows and columns so `select(x, x1, y, y1, z, z1, q, q1, t, t1` is not viable for me to use. I need a i+1 kind of sequantial loop going or something similar. Also your solution generates a df with 2 variables of 50 observations, what I am looking for is a df with the same amount of variables and observations as df_abt (now renamed df_AB)

Comment: You're right, the solution using `select()` is pretty ad hoc, but it's easy to come up with something that generalizes to arbitrary n of rows and columns. For example, the following works just as well:

`df_abt <- dfA %>%
  bind_cols(dfB)

variables <- paste0(rep(c('x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 't'), each = 2), rep(c('', '1'), 10))

df_abt %>%
  select(paste(variables))`

Comment: On my computer, `df_dist <- map2_df(df_abt, df_cdt, ~ sqrt((.x - .y)^2))` works - it generates a dataframe with 10 variables and 10 rows. It shouldn't make much difference, but have you tried just copy-pasting all my code?